# Creating a visit column based on a site ID and a date

Tags: r

I have a data set with unique sites that are visited multiple times each. I have a site ID column and a date column. I want to generate a visit column within each unique site ID that assigns a 1 for the first date, a 2 for the second etc... for each time a site is visited. Here is what my input data looks like:

```
 df<- data.frame(id = c("A, "A, "A, "B", "B", "B", "C"),
         date = c("05-01-2012", "05-12-2012", "05-20-2012", "05-01-2012", "05-01-2012", 
                  "05-11- 2012", "05-07-2012"))

    id date
    A  05-01-2012
    A  05-12-2012
    A  05-20-2012
    B  05-01-2012
    B  05-01-2012
    B  05-11-2012
    C  05-07-2012
```

Here is what I want to generate:

```
    id date       visit
    A  05-01-2012 1
    A  05-12-2012 2
    A  05-20-2012 3
    B  05-01-2012 1
    B  05-01-2012 1
    B  05-11-2012 2
    C  05-07-2012 1
```

I have tried `df_%>% group_by(id) %>%summarise(visit=(setDT(df)[, visit := .GRP, by = date]))`but it assigns a unique visit value for each date, but not within an ID, so my visits values just keep climbing instead of restarting at 1 for every new ID.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `match` to create the column and instead of `summarise` it would be `mutate`. `summarise` expects the output to return a single row per each group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(visit = match(date, unique(date)))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
#  id    date       visit
#  <fct> <fct>      <int>
#1 A     05-01-2012     1
#2 A     05-12-2012     2
#3 A     05-20-2012     3
#4 B     05-01-2012     1
#5 B     05-01-2012     1
#6 B     05-11-2012     2
#7 C     05-07-2012     1
```